# Check if a file on a website is within the last 30 days

Tags: bash, date, scripting

I'm looking at checking whether or not the XProtect file on an Apple machine is up to date. I've got the methodology down for checking the .plist on their website against the local .plist containing this information. However we would now like to allow users to carry on if the current date is within the last 30 days of when Apple posted up the latest .plist online. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to compare the online published date to the local time and if the online version is within the last 30 days allow the script to continue.

```
curl -sL http://google.com -o /dev/null
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    URL=http://configuration.apple.com/configurations/macosx/xprotect/3/clientConfiguration.plist
    curl -s $URL | awk '/\<\?xml/{i++}i' > /tmp/meta.plist
    urlresult=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :meta:Version" "/tmp/meta.plist")
    locresult=$(defaults read /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/XProtect.meta Version)
    if [ find /tmp/meta.plist -mtime -30 ]; then
        xpresult="Within 30 days"
    else
        if [ "$urlresult" == "$locresult" ]; then
            xpresult="Up to date"
        else
            xpresult="out of date"
        fi
    fi
fi
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ find /tmp/meta.plist -mtime -30 ]; then
```

`find` is an external command so it musn't be enclosed around `[ ]`. And perhaps it should be

```
if find /tmp/meta.plist -mtime -30 >/dev/null; then
```

>/dev/null suppresses output.

Comment: That does the comparison portion correctly thank you, however is there a way for me to look at the `$URL` for the file to compare it to? When I try it tells me that the file cannot be found?

Comment: I don't follow sorry. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, I'm actually looking to see if the information posted at the variable `URL` has been updated within the past 30 days. So I'd like to see if the file located at `http://configuration.apple.com/configurations/macosx/xprotect/3/clientConfiguration.plist` was posted 30 days or less from today.

Comment: That's rather complex and may depend on the implementation of the server. Sorry but I don't think I can help with that. Perhaps you can ask another question about how to do that specific task.

Comment: No problem, thank you for the help! The date check works great!